# MySQL/InnoDB Connections Limit

Tags: mysql, performance, centos, innodb

Centos 6.5

I am in the process of tuning my MySQL InnoDB server for Roundcube webmail. Here's my current my.conf:

```
[mysqld]
local-infile=0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

innodb_buffer_pool_size=10240M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=1024M
innodb_log_buffer_size=64M
innodb_thread_concurrency=12

slow_query_log=1 
slow_query_log_file=mysql-slow.log 


[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=500K
innodb_log_buffer_size=500K
innodb_thread_concurrency=2
```

I logged into mysql and ran show status like '%onn%'; and it returned:

```
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| Aborted_connects         | 2     |
| Connections              | 2762  |
| Max_used_connections     | 7     |
| Ssl_client_connects      | 0     |
| Ssl_connect_renegotiates | 0     |
| Ssl_finished_connects    | 0     |
| Threads_connected        | 3     |
+--------------------------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am hearing slow performance coming from my Roundcube webmail users and was wondering why my connections is 2762 and keeps growing when I don't have a max_connections set. so:

Questions 1: why does my connections keep growing and is that okay? Here's how I checked it:

```
mysql> select @@max_connections;
+-------------------+
| @@max_connections |
+-------------------+
|               151 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> show processlist;
+------+-------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| Id   | User  | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State | Info             |
+------+-------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| 2296 | admin | localhost | NULL | Query   |    0 | NULL  | show processlist |
| 3221 | admin | localhost | psa  | Sleep   |   55 |       | NULL             |
| 3222 | admin | localhost | psa  | Sleep   |   55 |       | NULL             |
+------+-------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Question 2: Should I set some other parameters to give mysql and innodb more resources for performance? Increasing the buffer_pool_size to 10GB helped tremendously, I am wondering if I missed something else?

Here's my innodb engine status:

```
--------------------------------------------------+
| InnoDB |      | 
=====================================
141001 13:09:27 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 6 seconds
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 197, signal count 196
Mutex spin waits 0, rounds 530, OS waits 22
RW-shared spins 302, OS waits 151; RW-excl spins 27, OS waits 24
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 0 11948976
Purge done for trx's n:o < 0 11948923 undo n:o < 0 0
History list length 15
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 0 0, not started, process no 26701, OS thread id 140085282813696
MySQL thread id 2296, query id 14827 localhost admin
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
---TRANSACTION 0 11948975, not started, process no 26701, OS thread id 140085281482496
MySQL thread id 3158, query id 14826 localhost roundcube
---TRANSACTION 0 11945958, not started, process no 26701, OS thread id 140085282547456
MySQL thread id 2127, query id 10139 localhost admin
---TRANSACTION 0 11945954, not started, process no 26701, OS thread id 140085282281216
MySQL thread id 2126, query id 10133 localhost admin
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for i/o request (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for i/o request (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: 0, aio writes: 0,
 ibuf aio reads: 0, log i/o's: 0, sync i/o's: 0
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
329 OS file reads, 4416 OS file writes, 2123 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 0.67 writes/s, 0.67 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 0, seg size 2,
0 inserts, 0 merged recs, 0 merges
Hash table size 21249871, node heap has 5 buffer(s)
2.00 hash searches/s, 2.83 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 0 3617058835
Log flushed up to   0 3617058835
Last checkpoint at  0 3617011323
0 pending log writes, 0 pending chkp writes
1546 log i/o's done, 0.67 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total memory allocated 11836708088; in additional pool allocated 12304384
Dictionary memory allocated 376320
Buffer pool size   655360
Free buffers       654975
Database pages     380
Modified db pages  11
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages read 367, created 13, written 2930
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
1 read views open inside InnoDB
Main thread process no. 26701, id 140073650968320, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 71, updated 1126, deleted 67, read 41194
0.00 inserts/s, 0.67 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 3.50 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
 |
```

My status:

```
mysql> show status;
+-----------------------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name                     | Value     |
+-----------------------------------+-----------+
| Aborted_clients                   | 0         |
| Aborted_connects                  | 2         |
| Binlog_cache_disk_use             | 0         |
| Binlog_cache_use                  | 0         |
| Bytes_received                    | 572       |
| Bytes_sent                        | 6217      |
| Com_admin_commands                | 0         |
| Com_assign_to_keycache            | 0         |
| Com_alter_db                      | 0         |
| Com_alter_db_upgrade              | 0         |
| Com_alter_event                   | 0         |
| Com_alter_function                | 0         |
| Com_alter_procedure               | 0         |
| Com_alter_server                  | 0         |
| Com_alter_table                   | 0         |
| Com_alter_tablespace              | 0         |
| Com_analyze                       | 0         |
| Com_backup_table                  | 0         |
| Com_begin                         | 0         |
| Com_binlog                        | 0         |
| Com_call_procedure                | 0         |
| Com_change_db                     | 0         |
| Com_change_master                 | 0         |
| Com_check                         | 0         |
| Com_checksum                      | 0         |
| Com_commit                        | 0         |
| Com_create_db                     | 0         |
| Com_create_event                  | 0         |
| Com_create_function               | 0         |
| Com_create_index                  | 0         |
| Com_create_procedure              | 0         |
| Com_create_server                 | 0         |
| Com_create_table                  | 0         |
| Com_create_trigger                | 0         |
| Com_create_udf                    | 0         |
| Com_create_user                   | 0         |
| Com_create_view                   | 0         |
| Com_dealloc_sql                   | 0         |
| Com_delete                        | 0         |
| Com_delete_multi                  | 0         |
| Com_do                            | 0         |
| Com_drop_db                       | 0         |
| Com_drop_event                    | 0         |
| Com_drop_function                 | 0         |
| Com_drop_index                    | 0         |
| Com_drop_procedure                | 0         |
| Com_drop_server                   | 0         |
| Com_drop_table                    | 0         |
| Com_drop_trigger                  | 0         |
| Com_drop_user                     | 0         |
| Com_drop_view                     | 0         |
| Com_empty_query                   | 0         |
| Com_execute_sql                   | 0         |
| Com_flush                         | 0         |
| Com_grant                         | 0         |
| Com_ha_close                      | 0         |
| Com_ha_open                       | 0         |
| Com_ha_read                       | 0         |
| Com_help                          | 0         |
| Com_insert                        | 0         |
| Com_insert_select                 | 0         |
| Com_install_plugin                | 0         |
| Com_kill                          | 0         |
| Com_load                          | 0         |
| Com_load_master_data              | 0         |
| Com_load_master_table             | 0         |
| Com_lock_tables                   | 0         |
| Com_optimize                      | 0         |
| Com_preload_keys                  | 0         |
| Com_prepare_sql                   | 0         |
| Com_purge                         | 0         |
| Com_purge_before_date             | 0         |
| Com_release_savepoint             | 0         |
| Com_rename_table                  | 0         |
| Com_rename_user                   | 0         |
| Com_repair                        | 0         |
| Com_replace                       | 0         |
| Com_replace_select                | 0         |
| Com_reset                         | 0         |
| Com_restore_table                 | 0         |
| Com_revoke                        | 0         |
| Com_revoke_all                    | 0         |
| Com_rollback                      | 0         |
| Com_rollback_to_savepoint         | 0         |
| Com_savepoint                     | 0         |
| Com_select                        | 3         |
| Com_set_option                    | 0         |
| Com_show_authors                  | 0         |
| Com_show_binlog_events            | 0         |
| Com_show_binlogs                  | 0         |
| Com_show_charsets                 | 0         |
| Com_show_collations               | 0         |
| Com_show_column_types             | 0         |
| Com_show_contributors             | 0         |
| Com_show_create_db                | 0         |
| Com_show_create_event             | 0         |
| Com_show_create_func              | 0         |
| Com_show_create_proc              | 0         |
| Com_show_create_table             | 0         |
| Com_show_create_trigger           | 0         |
| Com_show_databases                | 0         |
| Com_show_engine_logs              | 0         |
| Com_show_engine_mutex             | 0         |
| Com_show_engine_status            | 1         |
| Com_show_events                   | 0         |
| Com_show_errors                   | 0         |
| Com_show_fields                   | 0         |
| Com_show_function_status          | 0         |
| Com_show_grants                   | 0         |
| Com_show_keys                     | 0         |
| Com_show_master_status            | 0         |
| Com_show_new_master               | 0         |
| Com_show_open_tables              | 0         |
| Com_show_plugins                  | 0         |
| Com_show_privileges               | 0         |
| Com_show_procedure_status         | 0         |
| Com_show_processlist              | 1         |
| Com_show_profile                  | 0         |
| Com_show_profiles                 | 0         |
| Com_show_slave_hosts              | 0         |
| Com_show_slave_status             | 0         |
| Com_show_status                   | 6         |
| Com_show_storage_engines          | 0         |
| Com_show_table_status             | 0         |
| Com_show_tables                   | 0         |
| Com_show_triggers                 | 0         |
| Com_show_variables                | 0         |
| Com_show_warnings                 | 0         |
| Com_slave_start                   | 0         |
| Com_slave_stop                    | 0         |
| Com_stmt_close                    | 0         |
| Com_stmt_execute                  | 0         |
| Com_stmt_fetch                    | 0         |
| Com_stmt_prepare                  | 0         |
| Com_stmt_reprepare                | 0         |
| Com_stmt_reset                    | 0         |
| Com_stmt_send_long_data           | 0         |
| Com_truncate                      | 0         |
| Com_uninstall_plugin              | 0         |
| Com_unlock_tables                 | 0         |
| Com_update                        | 0         |
| Com_update_multi                  | 0         |
| Com_xa_commit                     | 0         |
| Com_xa_end                        | 0         |
| Com_xa_prepare                    | 0         |
| Com_xa_recover                    | 0         |
| Com_xa_rollback                   | 0         |
| Com_xa_start                      | 0         |
| Compression                       | OFF       |
| Connections                       | 3514      |
| Created_tmp_disk_tables           | 0         |
| Created_tmp_files                 | 5         |
| Created_tmp_tables                | 0         |
| Delayed_errors                    | 0         |
| Delayed_insert_threads            | 0         |
| Delayed_writes                    | 0         |
| Flush_commands                    | 1         |
| Handler_commit                    | 0         |
| Handler_delete                    | 0         |
| Handler_discover                  | 0         |
| Handler_prepare                   | 0         |
| Handler_read_first                | 0         |
| Handler_read_key                  | 0         |
| Handler_read_next                 | 0         |
| Handler_read_prev                 | 0         |
| Handler_read_rnd                  | 0         |
| Handler_read_rnd_next             | 0         |
| Handler_rollback                  | 0         |
| Handler_savepoint                 | 0         |
| Handler_savepoint_rollback        | 0         |
| Handler_update                    | 0         |
| Handler_write                     | 0         |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data     | 380       |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty    | 4         |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed  | 3334      |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free     | 654974    |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc     | 6         |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total    | 655360    |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd | 1         |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_seq | 0         |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests  | 87189     |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_reads          | 316       |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free      | 0         |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests | 16018     |
| Innodb_data_fsyncs                | 2366      |
| Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs        | 0         |
| Innodb_data_pending_reads         | 0         |
| Innodb_data_pending_writes        | 0         |
| Innodb_data_read                  | 8196096   |
| Innodb_data_reads                 | 329       |
| Innodb_data_writes                | 4983      |
| Innodb_data_written               | 118115840 |
| Innodb_dblwr_pages_written        | 3334      |
| Innodb_dblwr_writes               | 329       |
| Innodb_log_waits                  | 0         |
| Innodb_log_write_requests         | 18114     |
| Innodb_log_writes                 | 1542      |
| Innodb_os_log_fsyncs              | 1713      |
| Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs      | 0         |
| Innodb_os_log_pending_writes      | 0         |
| Innodb_os_log_written             | 8781312   |
| Innodb_page_size                  | 16384     |
| Innodb_pages_created              | 13        |
| Innodb_pages_read                 | 367       |
| Innodb_pages_written              | 3334      |
| Innodb_row_lock_current_waits     | 0         |
| Innodb_row_lock_time              | 0         |
| Innodb_row_lock_time_avg          | 0         |
| Innodb_row_lock_time_max          | 0         |
| Innodb_row_lock_waits             | 1         |
| Innodb_rows_deleted               | 75        |
| Innodb_rows_inserted              | 75        |
| Innodb_rows_read                  | 42750     |
| Innodb_rows_updated               | 1252      |
| Key_blocks_not_flushed            | 0         |
| Key_blocks_unused                 | 6693      |
| Key_blocks_used                   | 8         |
| Key_read_requests                 | 2034      |
| Key_reads                         | 4         |
| Key_write_requests                | 702       |
| Key_writes                        | 0         |
| Last_query_cost                   | 0.000000  |
| Max_used_connections              | 7         |
| Not_flushed_delayed_rows          | 0         |
| Open_files                        | 7         |
| Open_streams                      | 0         |
| Open_table_definitions            | 71        |
| Open_tables                       | 64        |
| Opened_files                      | 808       |
| Opened_table_definitions          | 0         |
| Opened_tables                     | 0         |
| Prepared_stmt_count               | 0         |
| Qcache_free_blocks                | 0         |
| Qcache_free_memory                | 0         |
| Qcache_hits                       | 0         |
| Qcache_inserts                    | 0         |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes              | 0         |
| Qcache_not_cached                 | 0         |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache           | 0         |
| Qcache_total_blocks               | 0         |
| Queries                           | 16423     |
| Questions                         | 15        |
| Rpl_status                        | NULL      |
| Select_full_join                  | 0         |
| Select_full_range_join            | 0         |
| Select_range                      | 0         |
| Select_range_check                | 0         |
| Select_scan                       | 0         |
| Slave_open_temp_tables            | 0         |
| Slave_retried_transactions        | 0         |
| Slave_running                     | OFF       |
| Slow_launch_threads               | 0         |
| Slow_queries                      | 0         |
| Sort_merge_passes                 | 0         |
| Sort_range                        | 0         |
| Sort_rows                         | 0         |
| Sort_scan                         | 0         |
| Ssl_accept_renegotiates           | 0         |
| Ssl_accepts                       | 0         |
| Ssl_callback_cache_hits           | 0         |
| Ssl_cipher                        |           |
| Ssl_cipher_list                   |           |
| Ssl_client_connects               | 0         |
| Ssl_connect_renegotiates          | 0         |
| Ssl_ctx_verify_depth              | 0         |
| Ssl_ctx_verify_mode               | 0         |
| Ssl_default_timeout               | 0         |
| Ssl_finished_accepts              | 0         |
| Ssl_finished_connects             | 0         |
| Ssl_session_cache_hits            | 0         |
| Ssl_session_cache_misses          | 0         |
| Ssl_session_cache_mode            | NONE      |
| Ssl_session_cache_overflows       | 0         |
| Ssl_session_cache_size            | 0         |
| Ssl_session_cache_timeouts        | 0         |
| Ssl_sessions_reused               | 0         |
| Ssl_used_session_cache_entries    | 0         |
| Ssl_verify_depth                  | 0         |
| Ssl_verify_mode                   | 0         |
| Ssl_version                       |           |
| Table_locks_immediate             | 9200      |
| Table_locks_waited                | 0         |
| Tc_log_max_pages_used             | 0         |
| Tc_log_page_size                  | 0         |
| Tc_log_page_waits                 | 0         |
| Threads_cached                    | 0         |
| Threads_connected                 | 4         |
| Threads_created                   | 3513      |
| Threads_running                   | 1         |
| Uptime                            | 1818      |
| Uptime_since_flush_status         | 1818      |
+-----------------------------------+-----------+
291 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your status 'connections' will increment every time one of the 7 'max_used_connections' uses the system to access their data.

max_user_connections can be thought of as the high-water-mark for number of concurrent/simultaneous users at one moment since startup.